# How to use custom plugin in multi-module project?

Tags: scala, sbt

In a multi-module project, with one module implementing a custom SBT plugin with custom TaskKey, how this plugin can be imported for the project settings of another submodule.

If the submodule using the plugin is define in `submodule1/build.sbt`, then `submodule1/project/plugins.sbt` is not loaded.

If plugin is registered in `project/plugins.sbt` it will fails when loading top/aggregate project as plugin is not necessarily already built.

Is there any other way to define a custom task requiring custom dependency so that it can be used by a submodule?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I finally make it works:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {
  private lazy val myGenerator = 
    // Private project with generator code and its specific dependencies
    // (e.g. Javassist)
    Project(id = "my-generator", 
      base = file("project") / "my-generator").settings(
      name := "my-generator",
      javacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation"),
      autoScalaLibrary := false,
      scalacOptions += "-feature",
      resolvers += 
        "Typesafe Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq( // Dependencies required to generate classes
        "org.javassist" % "javassist" % "3.18.2-GA")
    )

  // Some custom setting & task
  lazy val generatedClassDirectory = settingKey[File](
    "Directory where classes get generated")

  lazy val generatedClasses = taskKey[Seq[(File, String)]]("Generated classes")

  lazy val myProject =
    Project(id = "my-project", base = file("my-project")).settings(
      name := "my-project",
      javacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation"),
      autoScalaLibrary := false,
      scalacOptions += "-feature",
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(/* ... */),
      generatedClassDirectory := { 
        // Defines setting for path to generated classes
        val dir = target.value / "generated_classes"
        if (!dir.exists) dir.mkdirs()
        dir
      },
      generatedClasses <<= Def.task { // Define task generating .class files
        // first get classloader including generator and its dependencies
        val cp = (fullClasspath in (myGenerator, Compile)).value
        val cl = classpath.ClasspathUtilities.toLoader(cp.files)

        // then loaded generator class, and instantiate with structural type
        val genClass = cl loadClass "my.custom.GeneratorClass"
        val generator = genClass.newInstance.
          asInstanceOf[{def writeTo(out: File): File}]

        // finally we can call the
        val outdir = generatedClassDirectory.value
        val generated = generator writeTo outdir
        val path = generated.getAbsolutePath

        // Mappings describing generated classes
        Seq[(File, String)](generated -> path.
          drop(outdir.getAbsolutePath.length+1))

      } dependsOn(compile in (myGenerator, Compile))/* awkward? */,
      managedClasspath in Compile := {
        // Add generated classes to compilation classpath, 
        // so it can be used in my-project sources
        val cp = (managedClasspath in Compile).value
        cp :+ Attributed.blank(generatedClassDirectory.value)
      },
      // Make sure custom class generation is done before compile
      compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn generatedClasses,
      mappings in (Compile, packageBin) := {
        val ms = mappings.in(Compile, packageBin).value
        ms ++ generatedClasses.value // add generated classes to package
      }
    ).dependsOn(myGenerator/* required even if there dependsOn(compile in (myGenerator, Compile)) */)
}
```

Not sure there is better solution, especially about the redondant `dependsOn(compile in (myGenerator, Compile))` and `.dependsOn(myGenerator)`.